# Dynamically adding child views to a ScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview

I have a `ScrollView` which has a `LinearLayout` as a child and which contains all the other views that I shall be scrolling like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/profile_fields_container"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/account_person_name_label" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/person_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:minWidth="150dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="@string/account_person_emailId_label" />
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/person_emailId"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:minWidth="150dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="@string/account_person_phoneNo_label" />
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/person_phoneNo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="phone"
                android:maxLength="10"
                android:minWidth="150dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="@string/account_person_password_label" />
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/password"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:minWidth="150dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="@string/account_person_retypePassword_label" />
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/retype_password"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:minWidth="150dp"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/learner_tutor_status_label" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner
                    android:id="@+id/learner_tutor_status_spinner"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/create_account"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/create_account_string"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
        android:layout_weight="0"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Now, when I try to add another view inside the `LinearLayout`(which is inside the `ScollView`) at the end of it, dynamically, it does get added but half of it gets hidden underneath the `Button`(see the button with id `@+id/create_account`) and I am not able to scroll to it. It means that it doesn't get added to the `ScrollView` *effectively*.

This "other" view that I added dynamically is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

    <!--Type of Tutor-->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/type_of_tutor_label"
        android:textStyle="italic"/>
    <com.learncity.util.MultiSpinner
        android:id="@+id/type_of_tutor_spinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Professor, Undergraduate, Freelancer..."/>

    <!--Subjects/Disciplines-->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/disciplines_label"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
    <com.learncity.util.MultiSpinner
        android:id="@+id/subjects_taught_spinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Physics, Maths, Computer Science..."/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Does anyone know how to make the dynamically added view as effectively "scrollable" ?

**EDIT 1:**

In case if anyone wants to know how this conditional view is being added dynamically, here is the edited version of the code:

```
void showConditionalTutorUI() {
        // Initialize the first time
        if(typeOfTutorMultiSpinner == null && subjectsICanTeachMultiSpinner == null){
            if(profileFieldsContainer == null){
                profileFieldsContainer = (ViewGroup)rootView.findViewById(R.id.profile_fields_container);
            }
            if(rootTutorConditionalLayout == null){
                rootTutorConditionalLayout = layoutInflater.inflate(
                        R.layout.layout_conditional_tutor_ui,
                        profileFieldsContainer,
                        false);
            }
            // Add the inflated layout to the last of the container
            profileFieldsContainer.addView(rootTutorConditionalLayout, profileFieldsContainer.getChildCount());

        isConditionalTutorUIVisible = true;
    }
```

**EDIT 2:**

Okay, here is the LayoutInspector's view of it:(The view that I am hovering over in the hierarchy(highlighted by a red border) is the one not being seen.)

[image]

Comment: Can you show how exactly you are inflating and adding the view into `ScrollView`?

Comment: @azizbekian : See the EDIT.

Comment: I see no exact issue in your code, but try to perform `scrollView.requestLayout()`, maybe it will work.

Comment: Don't you think? `profileFieldsContainer.getChildCount()` should be `profileFieldsContainer.getChildCount() - 1`

Comment: @Wizard : Nope. I saw the Android source for addView() and it is like if(index < 0) { index = mChildrenCount; }. Also, I tested with both count and count - 1, it is the same behavior.

Comment: @azizbekian : Can you tell anything from the LayoutInspector's hierarchy screenshot(EDIT 2) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add `android:fillViewport="true"` and `android:scrollbars="vertical"` to your `Scroll View`.

```
  <ScrollView
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:fillViewport="true"
     android:scrollbars="vertical"
     android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

Comment: @pulp_fiction It Defines whether the scrollview should stretch its content to fill the viewport. and scrollbars will allow you to scroll through content till end.

Comment: @pulp_fiction Do upvote also :). So it will be helpful to others also.